# The Google BigQuery service has denied access for this request. Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, tableau-desktop

I am trying to connect two BigQuery tables to Tableau but I receive the following error:

> The Google BigQuery service has denied access for this request.
> Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

In BigQuery, one table receives data from the GoogleSheet that is located on GoogleDrive. Another table is a regular BigQuery table. I join them within a query as I need the data from both.

I am the owner of the Google Sheet and BigQuery dataset (as well as BigQuery project).

What can be the reason for this? What permission needs to be granted, so Tableau accepts the data from the BigQuery table that pulls the numbers from Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been published by Tableau [here](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-code-015cfbe6-access-denied-bigquery-bigquery-permission-denied-while-getting-drive-credentials).

If you're facing the error,

> The Google BigQuery service has denied access for
> this request. Error Code: 015CFBE6
> Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery:
> Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

you will be able to resolve the issue by scheduling your query to run and store the (daily) data in a BigQuery in a view, you can then connect Tableau to that new source ie.the view. As the query is being run by BigQuery, Tableau won't need to access your drive.

Answer (score 0):

What credentials is Tableau using?
a) Personal credentials

b) Service Account credentials

1. If a), then double-check that you have proper access to both. I am not fully aware of what permissions Tableau requests when you establish a connection with BigQuery. But it is likely that it only asks for the BigQuery scope.
2. If that's the case you could try establishing a connection via a service account that has access to both. Make sure it has access to your table as well as your sheet.

If none work, you could create a BQ native query from the sheet. Your Tableau query would then reference that instead of the "drive" table.

Simply use something like in scheduled queries.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE mydataset.myDriveTableBQNative
AS
SELECT * FROM mydataset.myDriveTable
```

If you need your data to be more real-time you could also look into more event-driven push on sheet change (appscript).